Subscripting a custom \mathbin operator
I have a custom binary operator
\newcommand{\foo}{\mathbin{\bullet^*}}

I now need to subscript sometimes, but clearly I get

instead of

Is there a way to make mathbin pass the subscript to its argument?
EDIT: \bullet is already a binary operator, so my MWE is silly, but in my real case it isn't.

Use the embellishment argument type for \NewDocumentCommand.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{e{_}}{\mathbin{\bullet^{*}\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

$a \bullet^{*} b$

$a \foo b$

$a\foo_{p} b$

\end{document}

However, this seems to be overkill, because
\newcommand{\foo}{\bullet^*}

would do the same much more simply.


@Mico egreg never mind, obviously I am misunderstanding something. Sorry for the noise.

@campa I actually didn't note it, so I added \mathbin back; maybe the OP shortened the example…

You could define \foo to take an optional argument which, if non-empty, is to be placed in the right-subscript position next to \bullet. (Incidentally, \bullet has type mathbin by default.)

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[1][]{\bullet^*_{\!#1}}
\usepackage{newtx} % optional (Times Roman text and math fonts)

\begin{document}
$a \foo b$, $a \foo[p] b$, $a \foo[z] b$
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}

\def\fooA_#1{\bullet^*_{#1}}
\def\fooB{\bullet^*}
\makeatletter
\def\foo{\@ifnextchar_{\fooA}{\fooB}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\foo b$

$a\foo_p b$

\end{document}


